# Different behaviour after upgrade Vim from v7.4.326 to 9.0.813

Tags: vim9

I have 2 Linux servers (SLES 12.5):

- On the first server I have vim version 7.4.326,
- On the other vim version 9.0.813.

If I open the same file on both servers, Vim behaves differently.

On server with Vim version 7.4.326 :
[image]
So, everything is fine.

But on server with Vim version 9.0.813 :
[image]

Could somebody explain me what I'm doing wrong ?

Many thanks

Comment: Welcome to Vim :-) The content of the file looks different?! Can you confirm that the content of the file is the same? Is the content of the file modified by Vim if you just open the file and quit? Is the buffer in 'modified' state after you open it in Vim (`:set modified?`)?

Comment: Try opening the file with `vim --clean`

Comment: @VivianDeSmedt : hello, I confirm the content is the same but I can simulate the issue when creating a new file : vi test , add 2 lines (azerty on the first , 123456789 on the second line) and :wq. When I reopen the file, there is indeed a modified buffer (+ sign besides the only active buffer nr 1) and indeed, I can undo different changes after just opening the file. I'm not used to work with buffers in vim, so where is this buffer coming from ?

Comment: It looks like a command is executed after you start Vim. Like @Friedrich propose, I would start to start Vim without plugins (using the `--clean` flag).

Comment: hmm, issue not solved when starting with option --clean. I will install older, working version on the server where I have these issues. Thx for the tips

Comment: Try [How to debug my vimrc](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2003/10604); it's also possible there was a bug fixed between ~9.0.800 and the current version

Comment: @D.BenKnoble : thx for the link. The issue remains even after starting Vim with the default settings (vim -u NONE -U NONE -N)

Comment: What's the output of `type vim` in your shell? Try to use the absolute path or `\vim --clean` in order to avoid alias or function expansion. Also are you sure it's the same file on both servers? Can you confirm by comparing their checksum? (maybe one is corrupted or has different-n-strange encoding?)

Comment: My guess is: the terminal is pretending to be xterm-compatible, but does not handle specific xterm compatible codes. You should mention what terminal you are using and try to update them to the latest version. Also check if `:set t_u7=` works around it

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt : good hint : it seems I have the issue when using MobaXterm but not when using Putty. It seems we have an (very) old version of MobaXterm so I'll ask to package and distribute the latest version